# Remove lines from CSV based on another CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a csv file named `master.csv`, which has the following columns

```
link, name
```

And another csv file called `details.csv`, which has the following columns

```
link, name, price, desc
```

I want to match `master.csv` against `details.csv` and delete the rows from `master.csv` which already have details in `details.csv`. `link` column is the unique column that matches both.

Currently am able to read CSV file line by line.

```
filename = "src/master.csv"
filename2 = "src/details.csv"

file = open(filename2)


#loop through details
for line in file:   

    #code to get column link from details.csv using regex
    prog = re.compile('xxxxx') 
    link = prog.match(data)

    remove_from_master(link)
```

How the `remove_from_master()` function should be written is where am stuck. Both CSVs are not in same order, hence if iterate `master.csv` and check for link in each line per item in `details.csv`, it will take alot of time.

Is there any other quick way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you do it in another part of your code, but always remember to close your files.  Using `with open(filename)` handles opening and closing for you.

Comment: How about some sample data and output?

Comment: Sort alphabetically and then iterate over lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are not horrendously huge, you might opt to use the `csv` module instead?

```
import csv

# Open details file and get a unique set of links
details_csv = csv.DictReader(open('src/details.csv','r'))
details = set(i.get('link') for i in details_csv)

# Open master file and only retain the data not in the set
master_csv = csv.DictReader(open('src/master.csv','r'))
master = [i for i in master_csv if i.get('link') not in details]

# Overwrite master file with the new results
with open('src/master.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, master[0].keys(), lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(master)
```